# How to download Git only on Docker?

Tags: linux, git, docker, alpine-linux

I want to install only Git in the Linux container, but it wastes a lot of time due to too much "apt-get update" content. Is there any efficient way?

Comment: Create a custom image where you preinstall git?!

Comment: In what circumstances are you running `apt-get update`? Is this on your local machine? You could set up a schedule to do an update/upgrade image rebuild, so that when you want to do something in a container, it is ready for you.

Answer (score 13):

I will recommend to use alpine Linux which is just only **5MB** and with git it will become around **20MB**.

```
FROM alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache git
CMD ["git","--version"]
```

build

```
docker build -t my_git .
```

run

```
docker run -it --rm my_git
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only want an image with alpine or debian you could use a complete docker image from docker hub for that:

Debian Git: https://hub.docker.com/r/samueldebruyn/debian-git
Alpine Git: https://hub.docker.com/r/alpine/git/

In addition, you can build custom docker images on top of them so you don't have to install git later.

If you just want to install git later in you docker image I would highly recommend to pre install it like Adiii suggested.